# Select most frequent value between 2 values per id with conditions

Tags: sql, postgresql, subquery, aggregate-functions, common-table-expression

Is there any 'better code' than what I've done with cte ?

I want to select the most frequent value between M and F per id with the following rules=

- sex values different than ilike 'F' or 'M', not considered in frequency calc
- if most frequent calc not successful = 'inconclusive'
- if most frequent calc successful = sex value

here is an example:

dataset

| id | sex |
| --- | --- |
| 1 | M |
| 1 | F |
| 2 | M |
| 2 | M |
| 2 | x |
| 2 | F |
| 3 | F |
| 3 | 0 |
| 4 | f |
| 4 |  |
| 5 | d |

result expected

| id | sex |
| --- | --- |
| 1 | inconclusive |
| 2 | M |
| 3 | F |
| 4 | F |

what I've done :

```
WITH cte1 AS (
                SELECT 
             id,
            sex,
            RANK() OVER (PARTITION BY id ORDER BY count(*)) rn
        FROM dataset
        WHERE sex ~* '(F|M)' AND sex IS NOT NULL
        GROUP BY id, sex
        ),
    cte2 AS (
         SELECT id,
                       max(rn) AS max
        FROM cte1
        GROUP BY id
        ),
    cte3 AS (
        SELECT cte2.id,
                       sex
        FROM cte2
        LEFT JOIN cte1 ON cte2.id=cte1.id AND max=rn
        WHERE cte1.id IS NOT NULL 
        ),
    cte4 AS (   
        SELECT id,
                      count(*) as cnt
        FROM cte3
        GROUP BY id
        )
SELECT DISTINCT cte4.id,
               CASE 
               WHEN cnt>1 THEN 'inconclusive'
               WHEN cnt=1 AND SEX IN ('F', 'M') THEN sex
               END AS sex
FROM cte4
LEFT JOIN cte3 ON cte4.id=cte3.id
```

To me the code is efficient in a sense that it gives the appropriate result but it looks a bit bulky, I'm looking for improvements. Is there any ?

note: I've used `DISTINCT ON ()` but it can not retrieve id 1 = inconclusive (F or M depending the order)

Comment: "looks a bit bulky" doesn't mean anything.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You seem to be overcomplicating this.

I would start by filtering out values other than M or F, then aggregate by `id`, and count how many times each value appears:

```
select id, 
    count(*) filter(where sex = 'M') cnt_m,
    count(*) filter(where sex = 'F') cnt_f
from dataset
where sex in ('M', 'F')
group by id
```

I don't see the need for a regular expression match in the `where` clause, since it seems you just want to retain `'F'` and `'M'` values.

From there on, all we have to do is compare the counts. We can do it in an outer query so we don't need to repeat the conditional expressions:

```
select id, 
    case when cnt_m > cnt_f then 'M'
         when cnt_m < cnt_f then 'F'
         else 'inconclusive'
    end as res
from (
    select id, 
        count(*) filter(where sex = 'M') cnt_m,
        count(*) filter(where sex = 'F') cnt_f
    from dataset
    where sex in ('M', 'F')
    group by id
) t
```